# How to remove old versions of the Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00 appx package?

Tags: windows-10

Back when I installed Windows 10 on my laptop (LTSC 2021, version 21H2), there was a built-in package MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS that has a dependency on the Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00 package. However, Microsoft made the mistake of not including it, results in some features like the "Screen snip" button from the notification area not working and the wsappx process having a constant high CPU usage. This can be fixed by manually installing the package, which I did back then, and the problem is resolved.

Later, I had to install another app that came with a newer version of the Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00 package, so now I have two of them installed on the system. Since the old one doesn't really have any reason to exist, I tried to remove it, but I was faced with an error message:

```
Remove-AppPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF3, Package failed updates, dependency or conflict validation.
Windows cannot remove framework Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.30704.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe because package(s) MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS currently depends on the framework.
Removing all packages that depend on the framework automatically removes the framework.
NOTE: For additional information, look for [ActivityId] 7664d75f-2888-0002-f4dc-64768828da01 in the Event Log or use the command line Get-AppPackageLog -ActivityID
7664d75f-2888-0002-f4dc-64768828da01
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-AppPackage Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.30704.0_x64__8wekyb3d8 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (Microsoft.VCLib...__8wekyb3d8bbwe:String) [Remove-AppxPackage], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DeploymentError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.RemoveAppxPackageCommand
```

Upon checking, it turns out that the MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS package lists both versions of Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00 as its dependencies:

```
Name              : MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS
Publisher         : CN=Microsoft Windows, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
Architecture      : X64
ResourceId        :
Version           : 120.2212.3920.0
PackageFullName   : MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_120.2212.3920.0_x64__cw5n1h2txyewy
InstallLocation   : C:\Windows\SystemApps\MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy
IsFramework       : False
PackageFamilyName : MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy
PublisherId       : cw5n1h2txyewy
IsResourcePackage : False
IsBundle          : False
IsDevelopmentMode : False
NonRemovable      : True
Dependencies      : {Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.30704.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe, Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.32530.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe}
IsPartiallyStaged : False
SignatureKind     : System
Status            : Ok
```

So my attempt to remove either version of the package results in failure with the same error message, rebooting the system doesn't change the situation. How can I get rid of the old version and only keep the latest one? I have checked in a virtual machine with a fresh installation that the MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS package works just fine with only the latest version (32530) installed.

Comment: Try Get-AppxPackage MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS | Reset-AppxPackage

Comment: @Ramhound Reset-AppxPackage cmdlet is not available in LTSC 2021 (21H2, build 19044)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I didn't find a way to remove any of the two packages directly, I managed to get the desired result: only one Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00 package present on the system and MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS works with the installed version.

What I did was install the package with `Add-AppxPackage` again with switches `-ForceUpdateFromAnyVersion -ForceApplicationShutdown`:

```
Add-AppxPackage .\Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.32530.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe.Appx -ForceUpdateFromAnyVersion -ForceApplicationShutdown
```

Result:

```
Name              : MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS
Publisher         : CN=Microsoft Windows, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
Architecture      : X64
ResourceId        :
Version           : 120.2212.3920.0
PackageFullName   : MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_120.2212.3920.0_x64__cw5n1h2txyewy
InstallLocation   : C:\Windows\SystemApps\MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy
IsFramework       : False
PackageFamilyName : MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy
PublisherId       : cw5n1h2txyewy
IsResourcePackage : False
IsBundle          : False
IsDevelopmentMode : False
NonRemovable      : True
Dependencies      : {Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00_14.0.32530.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe}
IsPartiallyStaged : False
SignatureKind     : System
Status            : Ok
```